# Can we generate fcm token in Spring Boot on server side?

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know how to send the notifications but I am trying to generate the fcm token on server side.

Comment: Please consider to add your usecase and what you tried and did you get errors ? such details

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging tokens are generated on the client, when it first connects to the server. There is no public API to generate FCM tokens that you can call from server-side code (such as from Spring boot).